# I love good books

Tags: discussion

(My original title "Good books" was too short.)
I was just answering an "on hold" good book question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/150051/electro-optics-where-to-start-studying).
I was wondering if there could be some (always open?) good books question,
that could be linked to.
Maybe with a bunch of sub categories?
(And can I squeeze optics into EE... as long as the photons turn into electrons.)

Comment: No, there shouldn't be.

Answer (score 1):

I think book recommendations can be a useful resource, and while I don't have a strong opinion one way or the other they can be a little problematic on Stack Exchange sites for a few reasons. I'll take an example from here and a couple from Stack Overflow that are moderated using different styles:

**[Basic Electronics Books](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/616/basic-electronics-book)**

The Art of Electronics is at the top and I can't argue with that, but it's also mentioned in many other answers and a deleted one too (that didn't contain any other recommendations). While maybe not a bad thing in itself because  it means a lot of people like the duplication makes the page longer than it needs to be. Also when you allow multiple recommendations per answer how do I vote if I think one book is excellent and the other is terrible?

If you make it a rule one recommendation per answer that solves that issue but then it all ends up being many pages long. Even though that's only two pages the last eight answers don't have any votes one way or the other, I suspect that's more to do with the date they've been posted and that they're stuck down the bottom so they haven't received much attention rather than them being bad recommendations. For that matter what if a book came along that was generally accepted to be better and more up to date than Art of Electronics? It took over five years for that recommendation to accrue that many votes so who knows how long it would take to float to the top.

**[The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)**

That has everything compiled into a single Wiki answer so anyone with a reputation of 100 can edit it. I find that compact style much easier to read although the disadvantage is that the descriptions are quite terse and the only in-depth reviews are in the form of links to off-site resources. If there was going to be a book recommendations question here though that's the format I'd prefer and the only one likely to be workable for your idea of sub categories.

One issue it could bring up though is how the list is maintained and issues surrounding it. For example I could go to that answer now and re-arrange the order with an edit summary of "I've read both and Book B is better than Book A" but that's mainly a matter of opinion and the only way for someone to disagree is to roll back the edit which could get circular, and you can't expect a moderator to have read every book and <s>know</s> have an opinion on which is best.

**[The Definitive C Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)**

That's a bit of a half and half approach with a single community wiki at the top but followed by a lot of other answers, although the question is locked so no new answers can be added. I'm  not sure why they went that way but some of the recommendations I'd personally find most useful are actually way down the page(s) and not included in the wiki. Probably because they're a bit more specialist and fewer have read them which can be another problem with relying on votes to determine usefulness.

Anyway as you've tagged as discussion I thought I'd throw a few of my thoughts out there. I think if the community decides it's worthwhile it'd be worth trying to shell out all the potential pitfalls from the start. Personally out of the various ways I think the style used by the C++ question might suit a relatively small site like here the best and take the votes versus date posted aspect out of it, and any questionable edits could be discussed here on meta.